# glmaterialfv is deprecated in opengl es2?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I found some functions like glmaterialfv are no longer available in OpenGL ES2 headers.

like the following method,

```
 glmaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE,color)
```

How to set the materials using OpenGL ES2? I need to set both Front and Back ambient, diffuse colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed function pipeline is not available in ES 2.0. So everything that includes materials, lights, the matrix stack, etc., is gone. If you look at the official spec file, ES 2.0 was actually specified as a new API, not a new version of the ES 1.1 API.

With ES 2.0, you have to write your own shader programs in GLSL for lighting calculations, and a lot of other functionality that the fixed pipeline previously handled for you. The initial hurdle might look higher than it is for ES 1.1, but you will get used to it pretty quickly, and then appreciate the new power and flexibility.

You should be able to find some good tutorials for ES 2.0 online.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES 2.0 is not backwards compatible with OpenGL ES 1.1 - these are two completely different APIs.

Comment: I would not go that far. Most of the commands you need simply to display or draw something in ES 2.0 are from ES 1.0. You cannot clear your drawbuffer without calling `glClear (...)` and you cannot draw geometry without calling `glDraw* (...)`. If they were completely different APIs then nothing would be shared. In actuality, ES 2.0 is a stripped down version of ES 1.0 (anything related to the fixed-function pipeline was removed) with GLSL and a few other things added.